# Handling connections from multiple users on a server

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

I'm writing a program and I have a server that needs to be able to handle multiple client connections at once doing many different things.

I'm using the Qt library, so I handle new connections like this:

In the server constructor:

```
Server::Server(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
  connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), //server is a QTcpServer object
          this, SLOT(acceptConnection())); 
  qDebug() << "[" << currentTime() << "] " << "Server started.";
  server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, PORT_NUMBER);
  qDebug() << "[" << currentTime() << "] " << "Server listening.";
}
```

The `acceptConnection` slot:

```
void Server::acceptConnection()
{
  client = server.nextPendingConnection(); //client is a QTcpSocket* object

  connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), //When there is data to be read
    this, SLOT(startRead()));
}
```

The `startRead` slot:

```
void Server::startRead()
{

    char serverReceiveBuf[65536]; //A buffer for the data sent to the server
    client->read(serverReceiveBuf, client->bytesAvailable());
    handleConnection(serverReceiveBuf); //Do something with that data
}
```

I'm not going to give the `handleConnection` function because it's a bit long and I don't think it's necessary for the question.

My worry is latency. If I have one or two users, it's fine. But I haven't tested many concurrent users. There's a synchronization signal sent by the client that asks the server to verify the data the client has matches the data on the server. I'm sending this request every 250 ms, so with a few more concurrent users the client may end up waiting too long every 250 ms because of the other clients sending in synchronization requests.

At least, that's what I believe. Qt is pretty powerful, but I'm not entirely sure if when a signal is received that a new thread is automatically created to handle the connection. If I'm not mistaken, the current way I handle connections involves queueing, so that when the server receives a signal it'll process the requests in the order received. It's important to note that I don't call `client->close()` until the client terminates the connection themselves, so once `client = server.nextPendingConnecting();` is called `client` will always exist until the client terminates the program on their side.

Is this a good way of handling multiple connections, given that I'll be regularly having users send synchronization requests often? If not, how should I handle the connections instead?

Comment: It would be very counterproductive to launch a new thread to automatically handle new connections. You don't want more CPU-bound threads than `QThread::idealThreadCount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***I haven't tested many concurrent users.***

You doubt the number of clients that Qt can support, but without testing it, you're not going to know what that limit is, especially as the hardware your running on can make quite a big difference here.

I've had a few hundred simultaneous connections, each constantly sending and receiving data without a problem, but my setup will likely have been different to yours.

As for how you're setting up the server, there's just one immediate issue I see with the code you provide. In the function startRead() you should be aware that the data received may be incomplete at this point.

You need to know when you've received a full message. The simplest way is to prepend each message with the size of the message, in bytes, then on receiving the start of a message, you read the size and keep appending data into a buffer until you have a complete message, at which point you can then call handleConnection.

Comment: My main concern was if the bottleneck of the server would be server hardware or because I wrote bad code. For the `startRead()` changes, I send data from the client with a `QByteArray`, so I can just send the `size()` of the array first. How do I make the server wait until it's received `size()` bytes first, though? I know the second parameter of `read()` is the amount of bytes to read, but how do I make sure I only read the size of the incoming data first without reading the rest of the data? If I send an int as the message size, could I just `read(messageSize, 4)`?

Comment: The server doesn't wait, it exits out of readyRead and returns when more data is available. So you need to buffer the data in a member or static variable (QByteArray) and call handleConnection when a full message is received.